# Mysql queries crawl when switching servers

Tags: mysql

I ran into a problem last week moving from dev-testing where one of my queries which had run perfectly in dev, was crawling on my testing server.

It was fixed by adding FORCE INDEX on one of the indexes in the query.

Now I've loaded the same database into the production server (and it's running with the FORCE INDEX command, and it has slowed again.

Any idea what would cause something like this to happen? The testing and prod are both running the same OS and version of mysql (unlike the dev).

Here's the query and the explain from it.

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT showsdate.bid, showsdate.bandid, showsdate.date, showsdate.time,
    -> showsdate.title, showsdate.name, showsdate.address, showsdate.rank, showsdate.city, showsdate.state,
    ->  showsdate.lat, showsdate.`long` , tickets.link, tickets.lowprice, tickets.highprice, tickets.source
    -> , tickets.ext, artistGenre, showsdate.img
    -> FROM tickets
    -> RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    -> SELECT shows.bid, shows.date, shows.time, shows.title, artists.name, artists.img, artists.rank, artists
    -> .bandid, shows.address, shows.city, shows.state, shows.lat, shows.`long`, GROUP_CONCAT(genres.genre SEPARATOR
    ->  ' | ') AS artistGenre
    -> FROM shows FORCE INDEX (biddate_idx)
    -> JOIN artists ON shows.bid = artists.bid JOIN genres ON artists.bid=genres.bid
    -> WHERE  `long` BETWEEN -74.34926984058 AND -73.62463215942 AND lat BETWEEN 40.39373515942 AND 41.11837284058
    ->  AND shows.date >= '2009-03-02'  GROUP BY shows.bid, shows.date ORDER BY  shows.date, artists.rank  DESC
    ->  LIMIT 0, 30
    -> )showsdate ON showsdate.bid = tickets.bid AND showsdate.date = tickets.date;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                         |     30 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tickets    | ref    | biddate_idx   | biddate_idx | 7       | showsdate.bid,showsdate.date |      1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | genres     | index  | bandid_idx    | bandid_idx  | 141     | NULL                         | 531281 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | shows      | ref    | biddate_idx   | biddate_idx | 4       | activeHW.genres.bid          |      5 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | artists    | eq_ref | bid_idx       | bid_idx     | 4       | activeHW.genres.bid          |      1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I chimed in when you asked this question about the differences in dev -> test.

Have you tried rebuilding the indexes and recalculating statistics?  Generally, forcing an index is a bad idea as the optimizer usually makes good choices as to which indexes to use.  However, that assumes that it has good statistics to work from and that the indexes aren't seriously fragmented.

**ETA:**

To rebuild indexes, use:

```
REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK;
```

To recalculate statistics:

```
ANALYZE TABLE tbl_name;
```

Comment: You're assuming the table type is of MyISAM and not InnoDB - REPAIR TABLE is only applicable for the MyISAM engine. InnoDB does not have a comparable command.

Comment: It is a MyISAM db, and i had run 'optimize' as I thought that was what I was supposed to do. I've now run both repair and analyze on the two tables. big improvement, but somehow my dev&test machines are still faster than prod. Prod .39 sec, dev .18 sec.

Comment: @Cody - You are right.  To do this for InnoDB, you would just use a dummy ALTER statement.  Something like ALTER TABLE my_table TYPE='InnoDB'.

Comment: @pedalpete - Are the execution plans the same in test and prod now?  If so, then it might be the database size (are the test and prod databases roughly the same size?), could be a load issue, or could be some subtle difference in the hardware.

Comment: by 'execution plans', i assume you mean the script or queries used in testing? Those are exactly the same. The databases are the exactly the same size. The hardware on prod is slightly better than test, and better than dev, though dev has more ram.

Comment: by execution plan, I meant the "explain" that you get from the query.  If the data is the same, and the statistics are up to date, the explains should be the same in each environment.  The hardware might account for the difference though - especially if its more meomory or faster disks.

Answer (score 0):

Does test server have only 10 records and production server 1000000000 records?
This might also cause different execution times

Answer (score 0):

Are the two servers configured the same? It sounds like you might be crossing a "tipping point" in MySQL's performance. I'd compare the MySQL configurations; there might be a memory parameter way different.